# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on VirtualBox 4.1.18 reverts to last snapshot

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, virtualization

Somehow, my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS running in VirtualBox 4.1.18 (W7 Host) got stuck.. and I closed the machine.

Now when I start up the VM again, it reverts back to my last snapshot which is more than 20 days old. Fortunately I have a quite recent backup of my important data, but still, this is very annoying.. What could the problem be and is there a way to get my data back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was my fault - there is an option when closing the VM which gives you the possibility to revert back to the last stable snapshot - and I had it enabled, for some weird reason.